# cursor.execute(""" UPDATE SET sqlite3.OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to update a column cell in my database for that I am writing a single query and then

I get the error when I run my code:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "K:\Project\Python\Campaign\Experiments\insert.py", line 9, in 
> cursor.execute(""" UPDATE facebook_profile SET
>
> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error

What am I missing? I am missing some syntax it is very difficult to find out where?

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('miracle.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

record_id = 1
profile_life_circle_value = 1

cursor.execute(""" UPDATE facebook_profile SET
                profile_life_circle = :_fk_profile_life_circle,
                WHERE oid =:oid""",
               {
                   'profile_life_circle': profile_life_circle_value,
                   'oid': record_id
               })

connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

[image]

Comment: It's redundant comma before `WHERE`.

Comment: should I remove the comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not difficult to find out where the syntax error is. The syntax error message tells you:

> near "WHERE"

It always tells you exactly the position in the query where the syntax parser got confused about your query. In this case, it wasn't expecting you to use `WHERE` in the place you used it.

So what did it see right before you used `WHERE` that made it expect something else?

```
UPDATE facebook_profile 
SET profile_life_circle = :_fk_profile_life_circle, WHERE oid =:oid
                                                  ^
```

You used a comma after your `SET <column> = <expr>` clause.

Use a comma after the `<expr>` if you are setting multiple columns. But don't put a comma after the last `<expr>` in the list of columns you are setting.

It's useful to learn to read syntax reference documentation, like the kind found here: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html

[image]

This diagram indicates that you can assign multiple columns. Each assignment is separated from the previous assignment with a comma. But notice that given this syntax notation, there can be no comma after the last assignment.

Comment: Thanks its solve my problem. Its a one line statement and I shouldn’t use comma.if there is two line I should put comma in the first statement.